# Save Data when change activity

Tags: android, authentication, kotlin

I have a problem with saving the data when I change the activity.

I have a initial login with EditText, where the people can write the parameters for login.

Attach the xml code:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/portText"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:hint="  Port Tcp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/idText" />
```

When the user press the login button, the activity change.
How is possible to save and show the initial data insert to user, when he returns in login page?

Comment: Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Comment: how are you navigating away from login activity ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to basically save the login details on the phone and update them when the user clicks the login button. If that's the case, look at serialization and/or saving the information into shared preferences.

Comment: `have a problem with saving the data` show how you tried to save the data, and what is the problem?

Comment: Try to read about activity life cycle and the method onSaveInstance

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Teptis and @Nero said , you can use shared preferences to save your data at time of login.
Data stored using Shared preferences is available even after the application is completely closed. This is how you store data in shared preferences

```
     val pref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("RandomNameForKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = pref.edit()//You need editor for writing something to shared preferences
                    editor.putBoolean("user_logged_In", true)//You can put Boolean ,String ,etc whatever you want (boolean in my case)
                    editor.putString("login_access_token",response.body()?.data?.access_token)//String example
                    editor.commit()//Commit to make changes
```

Once stored ,now access it like this

```
     val pref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sameKeyAsAbove", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)//Same Key name used while storing values(Important)
    accessToken = pref.getString("login_access_token", "DEFAULT")//Same key name as above while storing string(Access token is a string variable)
```

One more thing ,you wont be needing editor while accessing data from shared preferences ,you just need it while storing data

just dont mess up with keys,else everything will go wrong

## HappyCoding

Answer (score 0):

[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) is what you are looking for. It would look like something like this.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val pref = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    if (!pref.getString("login", "").isEmpty()) {
        portText.setText(pref.getString("login", ""))
    }


    loginButton.setOnClickListener {
        val login = portText.text.toString()
        pref.edit().putString("login", login).apply()
        startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

//First Activity when button clicked.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Constant.prefs.edit();
editor.putString("loginvalue", portText.getText.toString());
editor.commit();
```

//Second activity

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
if(prefs.contains("loginvalue")){youtextview.setText(prefs 
.getString("loginvalue",""));}
```

Try this, tell if it helped ?

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences for your use case. The following is a sample code to implement what you are looking for.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

val sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

if (!sharedPref.getString("login", "").isEmpty()) {
    portText.setText(sharedPref.getString("login", ""))
}


loginButton.setOnClickListener {
    val login = portText.text.toString()
    sharedPref.edit().putString("login", login).apply()
    startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
}
```